# Way of salvaging "Two-zero-one-five puzzle" challenge?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The [Two-zero-one-five puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48917/two-zero-one-five-puzzle) was intended as a Kolmogorov-complexity code-golf challenge: the task is to generate and print arithmetic expressions for as many numbers between 0 and 100. Unfortunately, I'd overestimated the size of the output (and underestimated the size of a winning program), meaning that the best solution is probably to simply print a pre-calculated, compressed set of answers.

Given that this was clearly not the intent of the problem, can anyone suggest a way to salvage the challenge without being unfair to anyone who started working on it in good faith?

Some possibilities:

- change it from code golf to first solution (though then orlp has probably already won, with a solution similar to one i'd written beforehand)
- increase the number of solutions to be output (though orlp thinks that the most programs for solving this are likely to be too big to golf enjoyably)
- turn it into pure code golf with a minimum number of expressions (e.g. 75) allowing people to golf the program more aggressively similar to [Four fours puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12063/four-fours-puzzle).
- do nothing and leave it as a compression challenge

Comment: Frankly speaking, this may be more suitable for [puzzling.SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A bit late for that, given orlp's solution :-) My interest was more in how people would solve this algorithmically rather than what the solution is. Unfortunately, the scoring doesn't encourage people to post their programs, only their solutions. (Though I'm happy to accept this is a lost cause, if no-one has any suggestions.)